# Standard Heat of Combustion

Tags: thermodynamics

When considering tabulated standard values of heat of combustion (∆H° combustion) or any other similar value, the results are reported for species in their standard states (1 bar pressure, 25°C, etc). When something combusts, however, macro state variables such as pressure and temperature change. For the tabulated values, are the conditions kept at constant temperature and pressure for the duration of the reaction? Or is the reaction started at standard conditions and the temp/pressure/etc allowed to fluctuate as the system reaches equilibrium?

Comment: It doesn't matter what are the variables along the process. Enthalpy is a state variable, and is independent of the path taken.

Comment: Yes, but equilibrium is certainly affected by things such as temperature. Wouldn't this affect the tabulated value?

Comment: Essentially, to what final state does the calculate ∆H° go?

Comment: Are you basically asking how they measured those values?